# Proof that $\left | \left \langle g^{m} \right \rangle \right | = n$, where $\left | G \right |=mn$ confusion

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

I'm trying to prove that if $\left | G \right |>1$ is not prime, there exists a subgroup of $G$ which is non-trivial, where $G$ is finite.

I know that the question has been answered multiple times, [for example.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1133652/if-g1-is-not-prime-there-exists-a-subgroup-of-g-which-is-not-g-or-e)
But for many of the answers given, they say that "$|G|=mn$ with $m,n>1$, then  $\langle g^m\rangle$ and $\langle g^n\rangle$ are proper subgroups", in order to complete the proof.

However, I've come accross a theorem on Proof Wiki stating that [Group does not Necessarily have Subgroup of Order of Divisor of its Order](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Group_does_not_Necessarily_have_Subgroup_of_Order_of_Divisor_of_its_Order), so how are we certain that in the case above, that $\langle g^m\rangle$ even exists, and is it always true that $\left | \left \langle g^{m} \right \rangle \right | = n$ ?

edit: For the [Proof Wiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Group_does_not_Necessarily_have_Subgroup_of_Order_of_Divisor_of_its_Order) theorem, does it not apply to cyclic groups, as this [University of Washington PDF](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~greenber/Cyclic.pdf) states that "3. Suppose $G$ is a finite cyclic group. Let $m = |G|$. For every positive divisor $d$ of $m$, there exists a unique subgroup $H$ of $G$ of order $d$."

Comment: Presumably $g$ is an element of $G$.  Then obviously $g^m$ exists, so $\langle g^m\rangle$ exists.  But it is not true that $\big|\langle g^m\rangle \big|=n$.  There is a group $G$ of order $mn$ where $m=n=2$ such that $g^m$ is the identity for any $g\in G$.  It would be true if $G$ is cyclic and generated by $g$.

Comment: No. But $|\langle g^m \rangle | \mid n$. (This suffices for what you wanted to prove.) Quick counterexample: Set $g = 1$.

Comment: @QiZhu how do you get that $\left | \left \langle g^{m} \right \rangle \right | \: | \: n$ , and how does it suffice for what I want to prove. Don't I need to show that $\left | \left \langle g^{m} \right \rangle \right | \neq |G| \neq 1$?

Comment: $|\langle g^m \rangle|\; |\; n$ follows from Lagrange's theorem.

Comment: If you want to show that $\langle g^m \rangle$ is a non-trivial proper subgroup, then, as you say, you have to show two things: $\langle g^m \rangle \neq 1$ and $\langle g^m \rangle \neq mn$. However, for the step you are asking about (show that $\langle g^m \rangle \rangle$ is a proper subgroup) you only need to show the second of these two. When its order divides $n$ then it is less than or equal to $n$ and hence less than $mn$. Of course the question why its order would divide $n$ still remains.

Comment: @DatCorno: how? The naive application of Lagrange's theorem only gives $|\langle g^m \rangle| | mn$. What is the more subtle application of Lagrange's theorem that we need here?

Comment: @Vincent so how would I go about showing that $| \langle g^m\rangle | \neq mn$

Comment: @Vincent I seem to have misread our assumptions about $|G|$, my bad.

Comment: Hm, we get $\operatorname{ord}(g) \mid mn$ by Lagrange, so $\operatorname{ord}(g^m) \mid n$. If we're in the case $\operatorname{ord}(g) = m$ where $g \neq 1$, then we have already found a non-trivial subgroup, namely $\langle g \rangle$.

Comment: The idea is quite simple (as all answers demonstrate): Every element has order dividing $mn$. If one element has order $mn$, then this is a cyclic group. For a generator $g$ we can simply choose $g^m$. If no element has order $mn$, then we are done anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a bit unsatisfactory answer. I'd be curious to hear a more beautiful answer using e.g. Lagrange. Nevertheless, here goes:

Pick a random element $g$, not equal to the identity and look at the group $\langle g \rangle$ generated by $g$.

We know it is not the one-element group because it contains at least two elements: $e$ and $g$ itself.

We are now left with two possibilities. The first one is that $\langle g \rangle$ is not equal to all of $G$. In that case we are done and have a group of the type we were looking for without putting in any effort. This is the unsatisfactory case.

In the second case we have that $\langle g \rangle$ is all of $G$. But we also know that $\langle g \rangle$ is cyclic. It follows that $G$ is cyclic of order $mn$. Now, using cyclicity it is easy to show that the subgroup $\langle g^m \rangle$ has order at most $n$ and hence is a proper subgroup: just write down all its elements!

We have $g^m, g^{2m}, \ldots, g^{nm}$ and we know that $g^{mn} =e$ because $G$ was cyclic of order $mn$ by assumption, so this means that these elements are all the elements of $\langle g^m \rangle$. It looks like that there are $n$ of them, but as you point out in the comments we might have written down the same $k < n$ elements a number of times (actually $n/k$ times, showing that this is a whole number, showing in turn that $k|n$ but we do not really need this). What is not possible is that there are *more* elements than the $n$ written down here. So the number of elements of $\langle g^m \rangle$ is at most $n$, as claimed.

Finally you might worry that $\langle g^m \rangle$ could still be the one element group in this case, so that $g^m = e$ but then, since $g$ generates all of $G$ by assumption this would mean that $G$ had exactly $m$ elements and hence that $n =1$.

It feels like cheating because the assumption that $g$ generates $G$ does all the heavy lifting, but remember: we could make that assumption because in the alternative, when $g$ does not generate all of $G$, it would be even easier to find a proper subgroup.

Comment: You have that all the elements of $\langle g^m \rangle$ are $g^m, g^{2m}, \ldots, g^{nm}$, but do we know for sure that there does not exist some $k$ such that $1<k<n$ where $g^{km}=e$

Comment: Yes, sorry I should have mentioned that. Suppose that such a $k$ exists, then $g, g^2, g^3, \ldots, g^{km}$ are all the elements in $\langle g \rangle$ so that this group has apparently $km < nm$ elements. So we are back in the first case where $\langle g \rangle$ is a proper subgroup and we are done and don't need to look at $\langle g^m \rangle$ at all. (But of course we are free to look at it as it will provide us with another example of a proper subgroup of $G$. The more the merrier, right?)

Comment: I'll edit to encompass this

Answer (score 2):

I think you are missing several clauses in the argument.

Take  a finite group $G$ of order $mn$, with $1\lt m,n\lt |G|$. We want to show that it has a proper nontrivial subgroup.

Let $g\in G$ be any **nontrivial** element. Now, if $\langle g\rangle\neq G$, then we are done: the subgroup $\langle g\rangle$ works, because it is a proper subgroup (since $\langle g\rangle\neq G$), and it is nontrivial (since $e\neq g\in\langle g\rangle$).

So now assume that this is not the case; that is, that $\langle g\rangle$ is, unfortunately for us, actually *equal* to $G$. That means that $G$ is cyclic, and the order of $g$ is $mn$. In that case, $\langle g^m\rangle$ is nontrivial, since $m\lt mn$, so $g^m\neq e$ and $e\neq g^m\in\langle g^m\rangle$. Moreover, since $(g^m)^n = g^{mn}= e$, the order of $\langle g^m\rangle$ is a divisor of $n\lt mn$, so $\langle g^m\rangle\neq G$ (it has order $|g^m|$, which is at most $n$, which is less than $mn$). Thus, you have a proper nontrivial subgroup. Similarly if you take $\langle g^n\rangle$ instead of $\langle g^m\rangle$.

But this is all predicated on $\langle g\rangle = G$. Without that assumption, you do not know that $\langle g^m\rangle$ and $\langle g^n\rangle$ are nontrivial. For example, if you take the Klein $4$-group of order $4 = 2\times 2$, with $m=n=2$, and you take $g$ a nontrivial element, then $\langle g^m\rangle = \langle g^n\rangle = \langle g^2\rangle = \langle e\rangle = \{e\}$ is a trivial subgroup. But again, in *this* case, you get that $\langle g\rangle$ is a subgroup of order $2$ and hence a proper nontrivial subgroup.

So what you are missing is the assumption that $\langle g\rangle = G$, which is the "bad" case (for what you are trying to show). But just one of the two possibilities you are exploring.

Comment: O I didn't see your answer because I was busy typing, but it is the same argument

Comment: how do you know that the order of $\langle g^m\rangle$ is a divisor of $n$?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is true in general, but in the case that $g^{mn} = e$ (which is where Arturo makes this claim) then I can answer you. Write $h = g^m$ for simplicity. First note that the order of the group $\langle h \rangle$ equals the order of the element $h$. Let's call this order $k$.

Comment: Second we know, as Arturo writes, that $h^n = e$. Let's do long division and find numbers $q, r$ with $r < k$ such that $n = qk + r$.

Comment: We have $e = h^n = h^{qk +r} = (h^k)^qh^r = e^qh^r = h^r$

Comment: So $h^r = e$, but $r < k$ with $r$ the order of $h$. This can only hold when $r = 0$. But then $n = qk$. This last equation implies that $k|n$.

Comment: @panzershreks: In general, in any group, if $g$ is an element and $g^k=e$, then the order of $g$ divides $k$. Here, $(g^m)^n=e$, so the order of $g^m$ divides $n$.

Comment: @Vincent: The last part should be “with $\mathbf{k}$ the order of $h$”, not $r$.

Comment: @Vincent: In this case we can actually prove that the order is **exactly** $n$, but this is unnecessary to show that the subgroup in question is proper.

Answer (score 0):

Let $g$ be any non-identity element of $G$. Then the order of $g$ is not $1$ and so is $pk$ where $p$ is a prime and $k$ is a positive integer.

Then $g^k$ has order $p$ and so generates a cyclic subgroup of $G$ of prime order. This is therefore the required non-trivial subgroup.